# Matrices operations

Tags: matrices, inverse, block-matrices

My professors asked to find the inverse of M:

$$ M=
\begin{bmatrix}
I_p&0\\
A&I_q\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Therefore, to find $M^{-1}$, we calculate:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I_p&0\\
A&I_q\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
C&D\\
E&F\\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
I_p&0\\
-A&I_q\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How do I go from

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
C&D\\
AC+E&AD+F\\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
I_p&0\\
0&I_q\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

to

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
C&D\\
E&F\\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
I_p&0\\
-A&I_q\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

What operations did my professor use to get rid of $AC$ and $AD$ in the first matrix to just get $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the matrix equation

$\begin{bmatrix} C&D\\AC+E&AD+F\\\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} I_p&0\\ 0&I_q\\\end{bmatrix} \tag 1$

is to be interpreted in terms of matrix blocks, we immediately have

$C = I_p, \tag 2$

$D = 0, \tag 3$

$AC + E = 0, \tag 4$

$AD + F = I_q; \tag 5$

then

$A + E = AI_p + E =  AC + E = 0, \tag 6$

whence

$E = -A, \tag 7$

and

$F = A(0) + F = AD + F = I_q; \tag 8$

substituting (2), (3), (7), and (8) into

$\begin{bmatrix} C & D \\ E & F \end{bmatrix} \tag 9$

yields

$\begin{bmatrix} C & D \\ E & F \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} I_p & 0 \\ -A & I_q \end{bmatrix}. \tag{10}$

Comment: I don't forget friends and honest, humble people.

Comment: @Sebastiano:  thank you my friend; neither do I.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
C&D\\
AC+E&AD+F\\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
C&D\\
E&F\\
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
AC&AD\\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Comment: Thanks. Should I divide the last matrix by A?

Comment: You can factor out  $A$.